# Eclipse: Access Plugin A from Plugin B

Tags: eclipse, plugins, communication

What do I have to do if I want one of my plugins (Plugin A) to be able to access classes and functions from another plugins (Plugin B) ?

In the plugin.xml of plugin B I tried to add the required packages in the "Runtime" dialog under "Exported Packages" but it had no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the plugin.xml of Plugin A, navigate to the Dependencies page, and add Plugin B to the list of required plugins.

Comment: Ah, it's the other way around. Thanks a lot!